# sql query or command tool to append mdf file to windows azure SQL DB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure

I'm trying to migrate my ASP.NET MVC app to Windows Azure, but on my code I have a module that imports data from a ".mdf" file hosted on the server to my SQL-Server DB using the SQL-Server "`sp_attach_db`" and "`sp_dettach_db`" commands and then referencing tables with `{databasename}.{owner}.{table}`, now with Azure it is not possible to do it this way but I can't figure out a workaround, any idea?

Thank you

**Added: Conclusion**

It seems not possible to attach "on the fly" a DB to SQL azure and share data with the others databases

Comment: I don't get the benefit behind attaching/detaching db from an application. Can you explain the use case?

Comment: I have to extract 3th party data thats come from a external SQL-Server database and then publish the data preprocesed on my site like a datawharehouse.

Comment: I have diferent sources, like Excel, CSV, etc, but this is witch gives me headaches

Comment: So you expect an mdf file from the end-user directly? Are you using sql azure?

Comment: yes a backoffice uploads the mdf file, and then a process do the import job

Comment: Are you running a background job to perform the import? Like a web job?

Comment: Yes, I'm using hangfire (http://hangfire.io/) to do the background task.

Comment: I'm trying to migrate to sql azure, but I'm stuck only with this

Comment: Web jobs are an option, but I am not sure of its support for frequent I/O operations from disk. To abstractly put it, you can make use of technology like sql server express, or localdb, and connect to these mdf files. Be aware that your mdf file should be compatible. Post connection its just a matter of migrating data to sql azure instance.

Comment: Thank you for your time @deostroll I appreciate, thats a solution, but, until now I do the import job running only a stored procedure, with this I have to develop something that interact between databases, it is not direct.

Comment: Can you update your post stating how you came to the conclusion that its not possible to do so with azure?